# JSON return only the matching record

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, server

I'm trying to return a JSON object to Postman without giving it a "title" like:

```
{
    "name": {
        "name": "Three Rivers Campground",
        "lengthLimit": 25,
        "elevation": 6332,
        "numberOfSites": 12,
        "padType": "dirt"
    }
}
```

I want to get rid of the first "name", and only return name, lengthLimit, elevation, numberOfSites, and padType. Here is my methods code so far:

```
app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    let searchTerm = req.query.q;
    console.log(`Search for ${searchTerm}`);
    for(var i = 0; i<campgrounds.length; i++){
        console.log('Testing 4')
        console.log(campgrounds[i].name)
         if (searchTerm == campgrounds[i].name){
             
             return res.json({name: campgrounds[i]});
         }
        }
    return console.long('Not found');
})
```

The line I need help with is:

```
return res.json({name: campgrounds[i]});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: code could be optimised, but your looking for `return res.json(campgrounds[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line I was looking for was answered by Lawrence Cherone: "return res.json(campgrounds[i]);"

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility of having more than one matching **name** with **search string** in **campgrounds** then you may need to return a list like below.

```
app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    let searchTerm = req.query.q;
    cons result = campgrounds.filter(item => item.name === searchTerm);
    res.json(result);
    if (!result.length) {
      console.long('Not found');
    }
});
```